# Exchange Web Services jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

Is it possible to call Exchange Web Services using only jQuery's AJAX function? If so any code examples that will work? I am currently hosting an HTML file in the same directory as the Exchange.asmx from IIS. I am running this script in that file and I get a "Method Not Allowed" response. Any clues? (username, password, domain renamed in script below for obvious reasons...)

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Exchange.asmx/FindItem",
        data: '{"username":"username", "password":"password", "domain":"domain"}',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application / json; charset = utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success " + data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error " + data.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't be exposing your username and password over a GET request in the first place.

Comment: Yes I understand, I just am looking for a way to make this work on a local machine.

Comment: Actually I believe it's supposed to be a POST request anyways, I will edit the question.

Comment: EWS is SOAP. AFAIK you cannot call it using REST and JSON.

Comment: Didn't want to call it using REST, just wanted to call it as a web service. I have been able to call other ASP.net web services successfully but not this. If I find a solution I will post back.

Answer (score 1):

EWS will return XML, not JSON - a quick google gives this:
http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/
Not 100% sure if it's right for EWS or not but google on SOAP XML jquery or something and you should be able to figure it out.  It looks like it's on the right track anyway.

Also there's a good util out there for testing EWS SOAP packages that will help you a lot:
http://soape.codeplex.com/

If the Exchange server uses NTLM, you won't need the username/password as it would authenticate with the user doing the call.